# Using && and || to check installed tools

Tags: bash

I am testing if someone tools is installed in the system with `command`

In this case I am checking if `unzip` is installed. if unzip is installed the nothing happend but if unzip is not installed, the script will run apt-get update and apt-get install unzip.

All this I prefer run it in one all.

I am trying this command:

`command -v unzip && echo "[+] unzip is installed in the system" || echo "[!] unzip is not installed in the system" && apt-get update && apt-get install unzip`

With that command always I am installing unzip.

How can i do to install unzip ONLY if unzip is not installed?

Thank you

Comment: Short circuit is nice and short but then you get surprises. Just use an `if-clause` or braces for command grouping. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To group between logical statements, you need to enclose them in curly braces. The syntax is like this `{ ... ; }`.

```bash
$ command -v bash &>/dev/null && echo 'Installed' || { echo 'Not installed' && echo "Please dont" && echo 'Yes, please do'; }
Installed

$ { command -v bash &>/dev/null && echo 'Installed'; } || { echo 'Not installed' && echo "Please dont" && echo 'Yes, please do'; }
Installed

$ command -v notexist &>/dev/null && echo 'Installed' || { echo 'Not installed' && echo "Please dont" && echo 'Yes, please do'; }
Not installed
Please dont
Yes, please do

$ { command -v notexist &>/dev/null && echo 'Installed'; } || { echo 'Not installed' && echo "Please dont" && echo 'Yes, please do'; }
Not installed
Please dont
Yes, please do
```

Note: A semicolon `;` before the closing braces is important.